# Turning on the developer option in android - yuphoria

Tags: android, smartphone, firmware

Recently during an update to my **Yuphoria**. i just got stuck in Boot loop .so, for to install the stock firmware i need the device driver to be installed on my PC.I've tried installing the device drivers but it tells me to turn on the developer option.
As i am stuck in a boot loop. i am not able to turn on the developer option to install the drivers.i'd be grateful if someone could help me to turn on the **developer option**.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to better explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Simply download the device drivers for your phone and install on your pc.There is no need for developer options to be enabled in order to install the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

go to your settings on your phone and in your about phone, tap on the build number 7 times :)

Comment: Thanks for your response...but i cant do what you're saying. i cant go to my setting menu at all...I am stuck under a boot loop.